# localStorage not working properly/localStorage overwriting itself

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm attempting to create a simple to-do list and I've encountered two problems:

1. After refreshing the page, all the created elements are no longer visible on the page despite being in local storage.
2. After refreshing the page and submitting new values to the input, `localStorage` overwrites itself.
   Despite that, the items displayed from the input fields are from the previous `localStorage`, which no longer exists (I really hope this makes sense).

```js
const inputEl = document.getElementById("inputEl")
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit")
const clearBtn = document.getElementById("clearBtn")
const todoListContainer = document.getElementById("todoList")
const taskContainer = document.querySelector(".task")
const cancelBtn = document.querySelector(".cancelBtn")
const doneBtn = document.querySelector(".doneBtn")
const errorMsg = document.querySelector(".error")

let localStorageContent = localStorage.getItem("tasks")
let tasksItem = JSON.parse(localStorageContent)
let tasks = []

function createTask() {
    if (inputEl.value.length != 0) {


        const newDiv = document.createElement("div")
        newDiv.classList.add("task")
        const newParagraph = document.createElement("p")
        const newCancelBtn = document.createElement("button")
        newCancelBtn.classList.add("cancelBtn")
        newCancelBtn.textContent = "X"
        const newDoneBtn = document.createElement("button")
        newDoneBtn.classList.add("doneBtn")
        newDoneBtn.textContent = "Done"

        todoListContainer.appendChild(newDiv)
        newDiv.appendChild(newParagraph)
        newDiv.appendChild(newCancelBtn)
        newDiv.appendChild(newDoneBtn)
        //^^ Creating a container for a new task, with all its elements and assigning the classes^^



        tasks.push(inputEl.value)
        inputEl.value = ""

        for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
            localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks))
            newParagraph.textContent = JSON.parse(localStorageContent)[i]
        }

        errorMsg.textContent = ""

    } else {
        errorMsg.textContent = "You have to type something in!"
        errorMsg.classList.toggle("visibility")

    }

}

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    createTask()
})

clearBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    localStorage.clear()
})
```

HTML code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
      <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
      <title>To-do list</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2 class="error visibility"></h2>
      <div id="todoList">
         <h1>To-Do List</h1>
         <input type="text" name="" id="inputEl" placeholder="Add an item!">
         <button type="submitBtn" id="submit">Submit</button>
         <button id="clearBtn">Clear list</button>
         <div class="task">
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML code as well, please?

Comment: Html code added.

Comment: Thanks, please see my answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71010982/13765033).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After refreshing the page, all the created elements are no longer visible on the page despite being in local storage

That is because you are rendering the HTML only after the click event and not on [page load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event). To render the HTML for existing tasks stored in the `localStorage` you have to write a code that loops over your existing tasks in  the `tasksItem` and applies the rendering logic to it.

I would suggest splitting the rendering code from your `createTask()` function and create a new function for it (for example `renderTask()`), then you can use it inside a loop on page load and also call the function once a new task is created in the  `createTask()` function.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  // Your read, loop and render logic goes here
})
```

> After refreshing the page and submitting new values to the input, localStorage overwrites itself.

That's because you are actually overriding the tasks in the `localStorage`. To keep existing tasks, you have to use your `tasksItem` variable instead of the blank `tasks` array to create your tasks in and save them to the `localStorage`.

So, instead of:

```js
tasks.push(inputEl.value)
```

You would use:

```js
tasksItem.push(inputEl.value)
```

The same goes for:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < tasksItem.length; i++) {
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasksItem))
    // …
}
```

Comment: As for the first issue, I've put my code inside of that arrow function above, and the whole thing still disappears after refreshing the page.

As for the second, how am I supposed to use the tasksItem variable here, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Aesy Please see my updated answer.